# For loop in Pulp Python

Tags: python, pulp

I have a Pulp problem that is working fine and gives me the right values, but I want to clean up the code. Here is the part in question:

```
prob += (select_vars['MeatA'] + select_vars['MeatB'] + select_vars['MeatC']) >= 3, ""
```

I want to put this into a for loop, like this:

```
meat_count = 0
Meats = ["MeatA", "MeatB", "MeatC"]
for i in Meats:
    if select_vars[i] is not None: meat_count += 1
    prob += meat_count >= 5, "Meat min"
```

But that is putting NoneTypes into my prob.variables() and I'm not sure why. There are no NoneTypes in my prob.variables() when I run it the first way without the for loop.

```
# Print out the variables with their optimal value
for v in prob.variables():
    print("some none ", v)
    if v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `pulp`, so take this with a grain of salt, but I suspect you're doing your `+=` line too often when you have it in the loop. Probably that line should be unindented, so it's only run once, after the loop adds up `meat_count`. There are a lot of other differences in the different bits of code you show, but I have no idea if they're significant (e.g. `is None`, `>=5`).

Comment: Please post the definition of `prob`. What is it's type? This will help create a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `meat_count` in the code above is a constant integer. You are then adding the inequality `meat_count >= 5` to your problem. This doesn't seem correct - it seems more likely that you want `meat_count` to be a pulp variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you check the [Case Studies](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/index.html) in the PuLP documentation. There, you will see how to use loops to make general models that adapt to your data. Also: I'm not sure you're making a difference between python variables and PuLP variables, which is important.

In your case, you probably want to do something like the following:

```
import pulp
prob = pulp.LpProblem('example')
Meats = ['MeatA', 'MeatB', 'MeatC']
select_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("selected_vars", Meats)
prob += pulp.lpSum(select_vars.get(m, 0) for m in Meats) >= 3, ""
```

But I insist, check the examples to see what each constraint does.